# ios 5 simulate my core location

Tags: ios5, mapkit, core-location, cllocationmanager

I've got a location-based IOS 5 app that uses my core location to retrieve local data. I'd like to extend it to enable "armchair traveling" where I can move the little blue dot to some arbitrary location, as though I physically went there. Then I want my app to behave in the usual way.

For example, when I move my blue dot, I would like the CLLocationManager delegate method "didUpdateToLocation" to fire.

Some someone recommend how to do this sort of location spoofing? I'd like to leverage the CLLocationManager code as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your project in Simulator, at the Bottom of the Editor appears
this little Icon:

[image: Simulate Location]

Have a good flight !

Comment: But I want to build this into my app, and be able to move my little blue dot wherever I want,either by direct manipulation, and/or by entering an address.

Comment: I think this is more what I had in mind. I'll explore it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209084/changing-coordinates-of-cllocation

Comment: One final thought. If I explicitly set my location, but then try to leverage the location manager and it's delegate methods, my concern is that it will wake up, and track my "real location". So I need a way to tell the location manager "Don't worry, I'll tell you where I am, until further notice".